# Email Disclaimer missing on multipart/alternative

Tags: delphi, exchange-server, mime, indy

I am using Indy in Delphi to create and send emails to an exchange mail server.

For messages with only one part, the exchange server correctly adds a disclaimer. However if I create emails with mutlipart/alternative, with both plain text and a html message parts, exchange does not add the disclaimer.

I'm thinking I must have structured my email wrong?

Comment: So what is your question? How can anyone know whether you've structured your e-mail wrong when no one can see it?

Answer (score 1):

Can you check the FallbackAction in Exchange transport rules ?
If it can't add the disclaimer for some reason, it will either:

Send it without one (ignore)

Send a new message with the original attached (wrap)

Reject it (reject)

Maybe setting to wrap will solve the problem...